# how to Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

is there any Theme based approach to hide it in android 5.0 or above like in lower versions on Android?
i just know the one way given below

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried this solution?

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 } else {
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
      decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
      ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
      actionBar.hide();
 }
```

Comment: this is not the one i want , i said that i want the other way using Theme

Comment: This is the only way as far as i searched on android.devlopers.com , so i think there is no other way to do it via theme xml

Answer (score 0):

Just an make theme with parent Translucent No_action_bar theme an set it to the activity

Comment: can you tell how to do it what you said in words

Comment: <style name="MY_Theme" parent="Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar">
            

    </style>

Comment: there is no such theme Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar , i am getting error create theme Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar

Answer (score 0):

Create an style with the parent theme with no actionbar. You can do this in the style.xml

```
<style name="customtheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat. Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Set theme attribute of your activity in the manifest as custom theme

```
android:theme="@style/customtheme"
```

And to hide status bar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

For more info check - [developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: I want to hide the Status bar , this only hides the Action Bar.